# How to handle dynamically created item inside function without click event?

Tags: jquery, dropdown

In a dropdown box which I'm trying to not close it by clicking inside it, I want to close it by `clicking outside box`.
The problem is the box is created dynamically, so I can't access it using this code:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$('#products .add-to-cart').is(e.target) &&
    $('#products .add-to-cart').has(e.target).length === 0 &&
    $('.open').has(e.target).length === 0
  ) {
    $('#products .add-to-cart').removeClass('open');
  }
});
```

My HTML code:

```
<div class="button-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="add-to-cart dropdown-toggle" id="add-to-cart-{{ product.product_id }}"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i></button>
  <div id="options-{{ product.product_id }}" class="options-popup dropdown-menu">
    <a class="cls" href="#" id="close-add-to-basket"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
```

Comment: Is product id of the box you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `document` object in order to get the new created box element, Here is a working example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#close-add-to-basket', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).find('#products .add-to-cart').removeClass('open');
});
```

Comment: @Taplar: I'd appreciate if you help me by giving a detailed answer. I already fixed closing by button. Now my problem is closing by clicking outside.

Comment: @Kardo I was addressing an issue with the answer provided.  Not directing a comment at you.  Edit: And the inner lookup still doesn't need to do the find like that.  It can just use $('#products ...') like it was.

Comment: @Kardo, When you do `$(document)` you get the new dom object with all new created elements

Comment: That is true for the majority of the jQuery methods.  Including $(selector). @YouneL